# How to show gutter for git diff?

Tags: android-studio

In IntelliJ there is a gutter to the left of the text editing area that can show git diffs. I would like to have the same thing in android studio. Is there a way to make this appear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've run into this issue a couple times using Android Studio there are two reasons I've seen Git diffs not show in the gutter.

1. The Git VCS path for the project isn't set.  You can typically set this in your project by going to:

   System Preferences > VCS

Then hitting the + button and adding your Git root directory.

2. The project xml is borked.  Sometimes a corruption exists some where in the code directory.  Unfortunately, after hours of searching through XML in the .idea directory and other files and directories I was never able to find the culprit.  However, **simply deleting the project, pulling it down from source control and re-importing it into Android Studio** re-enabled the git diffing in the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the git-repository associated with project. And you just need to enable VCS, to be able to perform operations (pull, push, etc.). You need to select : VCS >> enable VCS. Then after, it is automatically able to understand the source-control associated with the project. You can validate, by selecting : VCS >> Git >> Branches.

**NOTE :**  I had been using git for version-controling, hence it shows "Git" option in the VCS menu list. This may differ based on your tool.